# Media Url Not WhiteListed when using whatsapp API from gupshup

Tags: gupshup

We are trying to user whatsap API, playing with sandbox from Gupshup, the API works if i use gupshups sample pdf or files, at teh same time if i user a pdf from public url it throws the error "Url Not WhiteListed", but i dont see anywhere about the URL has to be whitelisted!!

my payload is this

curl -X POST https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v1/msg / -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' / -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' / -H 'apikey: 65XXX6afed5XXX01cd0a6bXXXf0a2XXX' / -H 'cache-control: no-cache' / -d 'channel=whatsapp&source=917834811114&destination=91XX88XX5X3 &message={"type":"file","url":"https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf","caption":"","filename":"dummy.pdf"}&src.name=Coolbuy​'

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

According to support of gupshup bellow, you won't be able to send public URLs files, unless your App goes live.

https://support.gupshup.io/hc/en-us/articles/360014736559-While-sending-media-files-through-Sandbox-App-I-am-getting-Media-URL-Not-Whitelisted-error-How-can-I-whitelist-my-media-URL-

> You are trying to send these media files from your App  which
> is not LIVE yet using our Sandbox. Sandbox API is limited and only
> supports sending text message and media message given below:
>
> Image:
>
> JPG:
>
> 1. https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/jpg/sample01.jpg
> 2. https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/jpg/sample02.jpg
>
> PNG:
>
> 1. https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/png/sample01.png
> 2. https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/png/sample02.png
>    File:
>
> PDF:
>
> 1. https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/pdf/sample01.pdf
> 2. https://www.buildquickbots.com/whatsapp/media/sample/pdf/sample02.pdf
>
> This restriction is kept for media messages due to security reasons.
> You will be able to send all supported media messages when your app
> will be Live with your business phone number. Hence, using any other
> URL in Sandbox mode for sending media will give you an error message
> that Media Url Not WhiteListed.

Comment: My app has gone live. The dashboard for the app says LIVE  But Gupshup is still not letting me send media files that are not in the sandbox.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any solution yet?